# How to wring multiple arbitrary values for background-clips using tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to write the following CSS using TailwindCSS 3.
`

```
background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
```

I highlight that I have multiple background gradients and want also to have various background clips. The final goal is to have a button with a border gradient effect and a background color gradient.

Here is also the gradient background value that I want to make.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(279.45deg, #ffd317 7.13%, #ffb40d 92.87%),
      linear-gradient(279.45deg, #ffd317 7.13%, #ffb40d 92.87%);
```

Any help is appreciated

Similarly to this I tried the following code but with no success.

```
bg-[position:center_bottom,_right_-15px_bottom_-20px,_left_0px_bottom_0px]
```

```
bg-[clip:padding,_border]
```

Comment: `bg-[position:...]` seems correct, what exactly is not working? What is desired CSS in this case? About `bg-[clip:...]` - there are no `background-clip` dynamic utilities, so it should be `[background-clip:padding-box,_border-box]` - which is plain CSS basically

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I was hoping that there would be a `background-clip` dynamic utility that I could use. Specifically, `bg-[clip:...]` Unfortunately, there is no as you say and I can only use the pure CSS one. On that topic, how can I check the available dynamic utilities for **TailwindCSS**?

Comment: You still may create your own [utility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-utilities). I prefer to look at Tailwind [source](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/src/corePlugins.js) code - everything created with `createUtilityPlugin()` is dynamic

Comment: Thank you @IharAliakseyenka for the help. I was not aware of that.